# normalized tables in ruby on rails project, primary key wont persist into my other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I had made a ruby on rails project that was far more complex than it needed to be (5 models when all I needed was 3) upon making this change my code stopped working.

The error message is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UserFooController#create
```

and thats followed by:

Couldn't find Foo without an ID.

so i'm working with a many to many relationship

user --> user_foo <--- foo

the respective models are as follows

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user_foos

attr_accessible :id
#etc
```

user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :user_foos

attr_accessible :id
#etc
```

user_foo

```
class UserFoo < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :foo
belongs_to :user

attr_accessible :id, :user_id, :foo_id
end
```

so the idea is that from the home page you press a button that takes you to the user_foo form html to fill out the details for a particular entry into a foo.
the application works up to this point but upon finishing the foo entry details and pressing the submit button an error comes up saying that "Couldn't find Foo without an ID"

the code for the button is as follows

```
<%= button_to 'Enter Foo', user_foos_path(foo_id: foo) %>
```

the controller create user_foo looks like this

```
def create

@user_foo
foo = Foo.find(params[:foo_id])
@user_foo = foo
@user_foo = current_user
#etc
```

i'm pretty sure the problem lies in this controller but after hours of tweaking code I had to come on here to seek assistance. Any help or suggestions is very much appreciated.

here is the code that surrounds the button, as requested

```
    <% if notice %>
        <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <% end %>

 <h1>Your Foo Catalog</h1>

 <% @foos.each do |foo| %>
<div class ="entry">
    <%= image_tag(foo.image_url) %>
    <h3><%= foo.title %></h3>
    <p><%= sanitize(foo.description) %></p>
        <div>
            <h3> The foo Starts on <%= foo.start_date %></h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3> The foo will end on <%= foo.end_date %></h3>
    <%= button_to 'Enter foo', user_foos_path(foo_id: foo) %>
        </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use has_many_through:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_foos
  has_many :users, through: :user_foos

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_foos
  has_many :foos, through: :user_foos

class UserFoo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :user
```

how is your FoosController looking?

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  ....

  def new
    @foo = Foo.new
  end

  def create
    @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
    @foo.user = current_user  # i assume you have something similar to current_user
    ....
  end
```

in your form:

```
<%= button_to 'Enter Foo', user_foos_path(@foo) %>
```

Regarding the comments below:
I just realized that you are using a UserFooController, which you don't need at all.
What you want is an association between two models, for which there is no extra controller needed.
If you want to create a new few use this button:
    <%= button_to 'Enter Foo', new_foo_path %>
Or if you want to edit the foo use:
    <%= button_to 'Change Foo', edit_foo_path(@foo) %>

Comment: I made these changes but the wasn't any change in the result unfortunately

Comment: do you have @foo = Foo.new in your new method in the foos_controller?

Comment: I added @foo.user = current_user to my FoosController but still no change. the Foo_id really does not want to carry through.

Comment: I have a @foo = Foo.new btw

Comment: sure i'll put it near the top

Comment: I think I need a UserFooController because the UserFoo model contains additional info that needs to be filled out and stored. the userFoo model contains a series of booleans that need to be set upon entering a UserFoo.
am I using user_foos wrong? should it only store a primary and 2 foreign keys? as it is the go between for the many too many relationship between user and foo?

Comment: userFoo should only be there for storing the id's of the two other models. Everything 'special' should be done in the regarding user or foo model. You also don't need the primary key, but you can keep it because it doesn't hurt and maybe you will need it later.

Comment: right, thanks allot. So all the 'special' things should be in either foo or user. ok that makes things allot more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the page that contains your button `<%= button_to 'Enter Foo', user_foos_path(foo_id: foo) %>`, `foo` is nil. You need to check what it should be. Most likely you define in that page's controller `@foo` instance variable and just forgot the `@` in the view

Comment: the controller for the page that the button sits in looks like this

             class AppController < ApplicationController
      #blocking non-admin access to controller
      skip_before_filter :authorize_admin
             def index
        @ foos = Foo.order(:title)
        @ user = current_user
             end
             end

do I need to add something here to get a particular foo_id in a @ foo variable?

Comment: can you please show the code that surrounds the `button`. It seems that you iterate through `@foos`? Please add it to the description as it's hard to read much code in comments.

Comment: i've added that code that surrounds the button but its just html really. if you would like to see other code just say.

Comment: change the line with button to the following: `<%= button_to 'Enter foo', user_foos_path(foo_id: foo.id) %>`

Comment: It still gives the exact same error. I don't think the button is the problem, I think its a controller issue.

Comment: In your controller you do `foo = Foo.find(params[:foo_id])` and it fails because `find()` argument is nil. To check that put a breakpoint before this call.